# Speeding up a for loop containing a sum in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm wondering if it's possible to modify this loop to run faster.  When I run it with n=2000000 it takes about 25 seconds. Any tricks available?

```
for(i in 1:n)
{
    x[i] <- sum(runif(20))
}
```

Comment: Is x already preallocated?  You should post the full code of what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, it's better to preallocate memory for result object `x`. Many tricks can be found here http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
system.time(x <- rowSums(matrix(runif(2e6),ncol=20)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.108   0.620   0.748
```

Comment: IMHO a small modification is needed: `n <- 2e6; k <- 20; system.time(x <- rowSums(matrix(runif(n*k),ncol=k)))`

Answer (score 2):

Using apply can get you some speed increases.

```
# How many rows?
n <- 1000
# How many samples from runif?
k <- 20
# Preallocate x
x <- double(n)

## Your loop
for(i in 1:n){
  x[i] <- sum(runif(k))
}

## Using apply
## First create a matrix that has n rows and k columns
## then find the sum of the row.
x <- apply(matrix(runif(n*k), nrow=n), 1, sum)
```

Now test the speed:

```
benchmark(

  loop = expression(
    for(i in 1:n){
      x[i] <- sum(runif(k))
    }
  ), 

  apply = expression(
    x <- apply(matrix(runif(n*k), nrow=n), 1, sum)
  )

)

# Result of benchmark
#
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2 apply          100    1.08 1.000000      1.06     0.00         NA        NA
#1  loop          100    1.69 1.564815      1.63     0.02         NA        NA
```

The loop takes longer than apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the following solution:

```
x <- rep(sum(runif(20)), 2e6)
```

EDIT: Sorry, I recognize that you will get the same number 2e6 times.